# Operator |= in C++ and its usage

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

While i was checking some C++ code i found a rather interesting operator and was wondering what it does?    I tried finding it on the Internet but no luck.

```
index |= (image(y - 1, x) != 0) << 3;
```

The right-hand side is clear, it does a left shift by 3 bit if the result is not zero, but this |= operator on the left confuses me.

Comment: | is bit OR ,which is index =index | ...

Comment: Just to be clear, the `<< 3` does not depend on the result of `(image(y-1, x) != 0)`, it just happens that if the function's return is 0, the boolean result will be false (or 0), which shifted left 3 bits is still 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place bitwise OR. It updates the operand with the OR of the operand and the expression on the right.

Same as

```
index = index | (image(y - 1, x) != 0) << 3;
```